# Can mount my Nas from desktop which is exactly what I want but can't unmount

Tags: linux, unmounting

I have the following `fstab` entry:

```
//192.168.0.12/Public /home/mike/Nas cifs rw,guest,vers=1.0,iocharset=utf8,_netdev,noperm,noauto,user 0 0
```

This allows me to click on NAS under devices on my desktop to mount my NAS which is exactly what I want.

Problem is, if I try and unmount I don't have permission. What do I need to do?

Comment: What happens if you type `sudo umount /home/mike/Nas` in a terminal? Does it get unmounted then???

Comment: ^^^ use that, problem should be solved

Comment: There might be a clash between options noperm and user. If security is not an issue (= you're the only user), replacing `user` by `users` might solve the umount issue.